# Need help understanding 3 player voting game

Tags: game-theory

I started learning game theory and I'm trying to understand better things.

I came across this problem, but sadly there is not solution to it :

Three players must choose between two options X and Y. They voting system win by majority vote. Each player must vote for each of the alternatives and the one that gets the most votes wins (ie 2 out of 3). All players strictly prefer X to Y.
Which of the statements are true:

A-In equilibrium X must always win.

B-Voting for X is strictly dominant strategy for the players.

C-Voting for X is a weakly dominant strategy for the players.

D-Voting for Y is never best response

E-There exists an equilibrium where Y wins.

My answer would be that all of these are correct expect E. This is because All of the players strictly prefer X to Y, and for this reason Y is never a best response, Y is a dominated strategy, hence does not win at equilibrium.

Is my reasoning correct? Any help/tips is appreciated.

Many thanks :)